# VB.net DataTable select statement

Tags: vb.net

I have a datatable and I would like to get the MAX number from this table where Term Number (first Column) is a certain value.  If my datatable is declared as dtMyTable, I'm assuming I need to use dtMyTable.Select(), but I'm not sure if this is the best way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

`dtMyTable.Select()` looks like you're using Linq, so why not `dtMyTable.Where(<term number is a certain value>).Max(<column you want max value of>)`

Linq has a built in [Max()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use LINQ:

```
'Assumes integer and a default of 0.
Dim intMax As Integer = 0

'Filter the list by the "Certain Value" of the first column.
Dim lstFilteredRows As List(Of DataRow) = (From dr As DataRow In dtMyTable _
                                           Where dr.Item(0) = "CertainValue").ToList()

'Get the max value by looping through the filtered list.
lstFilteredRows.ForEach(Sub(dr As DataRow)
                            If CInt(dr.Item("ColumnNameWithMaxValue")) > intMax Then
                                intMax = CInt(dr.Item("ColumnNameWithMaxValue"))
                            End If
                        End Sub)
```